# Approximating CPU minutes of a backend server

Tags: azure, rust, async-await, hyper

I'm looking for a low-cost hosting solution for my rust/hyper backend server, and I keep seeing the term 'CPU minutes/seconds'. I know generally that this is a metric of how much CPU an application uses in a given amount of time, however, I'm not sure how it's calculated.

In my case, the server is usually idle, awaiting a tcp listener future. In my head, this is constantly consuming *an amount of the cpu* due to polling, but I'm not exactly sure how much, and I don't know how it would translate to CPU time.

Basically, I'm not sure how much of a 60 CPU minute allocation would be eaten up per day by idling, or in other words, how to guess how many actual requests I'll be able to process per day

If anyone has any experience with this kind of thing, I'd appreciate any advice, information, or further reading

Comment: "In my head, this is constantly consuming an amount of the cpu due to polling" -- only if you write terrible code. Well written socket code will sleep until you receive data, as signaled by events.

Comment: If you're following the [hyper tutorial](https://hyper.rs/guides/1/server/hello-world/), then you're using a `tokio::net::TcpListener`, which uses [IOCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output_completion_port) on Windows → CPU usage is zero while waiting for a connection.